# Need an algorithm to find all subsets of 5 integers within an array whose sum falls within a given range

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinatorics

I have an array containing 43 terms, and I need to find all possible combinations of 5 terms whose sum is within a particular range.

I have looked to previous posts, and have found similar problems, but they all have variations that do not suit my issue.

Comment: How about an example and your current code?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the array and expected result.

Comment: The simple approach is to generate all 5 element subsets and to filter out the ones that don't satisfy the constraint on the sum. When you know more about the numbers (e.g. are they all positive?) better pruning can be done.

Comment: Some python code to get you started: `[i for i in itertools.product(range(43), repeat=5) if 5<sum(i)<10]`

Comment: Well, really what I'm trying to do is determine which subsets of five are close to the average of the entire set, give or take a standard deviation.  I am assuming that the "sum approach" to the "average x5" is the easiest, but if anyone has a better idea, I'd certainly appreciate it.

Comment: Example subset coming..

Comment: 330
297
315
312
327
287
328
313
290
297  

If set average is 301.4, determine all possible subsets of 5 whose average is 300-303.

Comment: All elements in the set are positive, and can be repeated only once per appearance in the set.

Comment: I don't yet have any code to that I am working with, I'm just trying to figure out where to start

Comment: Do you really want the subsets, or the count of subsets with sums in that range? If you want the count, and you plan to scale up a lot, you might use the Fast Fourier Transform since you are basically convolving the characteristic function of the set with itself several times.

Comment: I need a comprehensive list of the actual subsets.  Do you think this is possible?  I really know very little about all of this, is there a site I can go to hire someone to write the script?

Comment: @Jacob Neal: There are quite a few freelance coding sites where you can ask someone to write some code for you. You might also try fiver.com. However, if you state what language you need someone might also write it for free, if it is a language where writing it is fast.

Answer (score 3):

If your target range is large, then you will have to produce most of the 43 choose 5 = 962,598 5-tuples of 43 elements. On a computer, that usually isn't too bad.

If the range is narrow, you can do better. One improvement is to make a sorted list of the triples of elements, sorted by sum, and a sorted list of the pairs of elements, sorted by sum. For each pair, take the connected sublist of sums of triples that give a total in the correct range, filter to those triples so that all of the indices used in the pairs are greater than all of the indices used in the triples (to avoid duplicated 5-tuples and duplicated elements). If the range is very narrow, this might take roughly c n^3 log n steps for an n element array instead of c n^5.